# How can I let a user input one of the shift values and then output the corresponding string to a text file?

Tags: c#, writetofile

```
using System;
public class ReadWriteTxt // Read and write to/from text files
{
    public static string cipherTxt()
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"myfile1");
    }

    internal static void decipherTxt(string result)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"myfile2", result);
    }
}

public class LetterArray 
{
    internal static string[] Alphabet()
    {
        var letterValues = new string[26];

        letterValues[0] = "A";
        letterValues[1] = "B";
        letterValues[2] = "C";
        letterValues[3] = "D";
        letterValues[4] = "E";
        letterValues[5] = "F";
        letterValues[6] = "G";
        letterValues[7] = "H";
        letterValues[8] = "I";
        letterValues[9] = "J";
        letterValues[10] = "K";
        letterValues[11] = "L";
        letterValues[12] = "M";
        letterValues[13] = "N";
        letterValues[14] = "O";
        letterValues[15] = "P";
        letterValues[16] = "Q";
        letterValues[17] = "R";
        letterValues[18] = "S";
        letterValues[19] = "T";
        letterValues[20] = "U";
        letterValues[21] = "V";
        letterValues[22] = "W";
        letterValues[23] = "X";
        letterValues[24] = "Y";
        letterValues[25] = "Z";

        return letterValues;
    }
}


public class Decipher
{
    public static void Main() //Main method
    {

        int res = 34;
        string[] letterValues = LetterArray.Alphabet();
        //Create for loop that runs through every possible shift value

        for (int shift = 0; shift <= 25; shift++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nShift Value = " + shift + ": ");
            // For each character in the text file
            foreach (var ch in ReadWriteTxt.cipherTxt())
            {
                string result = string.Empty;

                if (ch == ' ')
                {
                }
                else 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
                    {
                        if ((ch.ToString().ToUpper()) == letterValues[i])
                        {
                            res = i;
                            if (shift > res)
                            {
                                // print results out
                                Console.Write(letterValues[26 - (shift - res)][0]);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                Console.Write(letterValues[res - shift][0]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ReadWriteTxt.decipherTxt(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm working on a Caesar Cipher program that decrypts cipher text that it reads in from a file.
It lists all the possible shifts throughout the alphabet.

I need to be able allow the user to enter the 'correct' shift value (e.g. the one closest to what the decrypted text should translate too) and then have the corresponding string written to a file.

What is the best to go about this?

P.S. My understanding of C# is a bit basic so please be gentle with me ;).

Comment: Are you simply looking for `Console.ReadLine`?

Comment: Nope, it needs to be able to take the shift value into account and append the string corresponding to it to a file

Comment: You want the user to enter the shift, and then you want to apply that shift to the input and write out the decrypted text right?  So @test is correct in that your user is entering the shift value via `Console.ReadLine`, no?

Comment: I want all the shifts to be listed initially as they are, I then want the user to see which is correct then have a Console.WriteLine ask them which is correct then have it read in the shift number they enter and have the corresponding string written out to a file. I apologise if my explanation is a bit off. Not really sure on how to go about this process.